# sed - group does not match when including bracket

Tags: sed, regular-expression

hoge.txt

```
tsar@gmail.com
c2m_@hotmail.com.es
c72@hotmail.com.es.com;es
m7_@hotmail.es.com
cm_@hotmail.com
@pepito.com
```

Without group, extract email works.

```
$ cat hoge.txt | sed -nr '/[^@]+@[^.]+\.com$/p'
tsar@gmail.com
cm_@hotmail.com

cat hoge.txt | sed -nr 's/[^@]+@[^.]+\.com$/hoge/p'
-----
hoge
hoge
```

However, cannot extract username part from the email with group.

```
cat hoge.txt | sed -nr 's/\([^@]+\)@[^.]+\.com$/hoge/g'
---
(nothing matches)

cat hoge.txt | sed -nr 's/\([^@]+\)@[^.]+\.com$/\1/p'
-----
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

What is wrong?

Comment: GNU sed's `-r` option enables extended regex mode - in which unescaped `(` and `)` are used for grouping and `\(` and `\)` become literal `(` and `)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer focus on GNU `sed`.*

---

In the [gnu manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/BRE-vs-ERE.html) of `sed` theres's an explanation about the regular expression syntax and use:

> 5.2 Basic (BRE) and extended (ERE) regular expression
>
> Basic and extended regular expressions are two variations on the
> syntax of the specified pattern. Basic Regular Expression (BRE) syntax
> is the default in sed (and similarly in grep). Use the POSIX-specified
> -E option (-r, --regexp-extended) to enable Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax.
>
> **In GNU sed, the only difference between basic and extended regular
> expressions is in the behavior of a few special characters: ‘?’, ‘+’,
> parentheses, braces (‘{}’), and ‘|’.**
>
> With basic (BRE) syntax, these characters do not have special meaning
> unless prefixed with a backslash (‘\’); While with extended (ERE)
> syntax it is reversed: these characters are special unless they are
> prefixed with backslash (‘\’).

So depending if you use BRE or ERE you have to adjust the syntax to get the desired result:

BRE:

```bash
$ sed -n 's/\([^@]\+\)@[^.]\+\.com$/\1/p' hoge.txt
tsar
cm_
```

ERE:

```bash
$ sed -nE 's/([^@]+)@[^.]+\.com$/\1/p' hoge.txt
tsar
cm_
```

---

Now [you don't need to use `cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) with  `sed` and other utilities, just reference the file at the end of the command.